# Prior publication ignored

Tags: prior-art, post-grant, us6981040

In reference to the patent: [US 6,981,040 B1](https://www.google.com/patents/US6981040)

The specification of this patent seems to follow:

Gio Wiederhold, "Customer Models for Effective Presentation of Information"; Position Paper, Flanagan, Huang, Jones, Kerf (*eds*): *Human-Centered Systems: Information, Interactivity, and Intelligence*, National Science Foundation, 15 July 1997, pp.218-221.

This was also presented at Stanford University open seminars and accessible to SRI, where the owners of the patent were working at the time.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If you are asking whether the cited document is sufficient prior art to potentially invalidate this patent, then you should explicitly say so and provide a link to the cited document so we can read it.